# How to simplify function which returns an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a function which returns an object but I don't like that I gotta declare it first and then do forEach method

```
export default (data) => {
  const keysWithDotsObject = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach((keyWithDot) => {
    Object.keys(data[keyWithDot]).forEach((key) => {
      keysWithDotsObject[`${keyWithDot}.${key}`] = data[keyWithDot][key];
    });
  });
  return keysWithDotsObject;
};
```

I think there should be something like this

```
export default (data) => {
  const keysWithDotsObject = Object.keys(data).map((keyWithDot) => {
    Object.keys(data[keyWithDot]).map((key) => ({
      [`${keyWithDot}.${key}`]: data[keyWithDot][key],
    }));
  });
  return keysWithDotsObject;
};
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work.

PS: In this part --

```
[`${keyWithDot}.${key}`]
```

-- I'm trying to create a key with a name separated by a dot (I don't like that, but that's what back-end wants me to)

Input :

```
Query1 = {
  locus_ids: [25, 26],
  microorganism_ids: [12],
};
```

Output :

```
Query1.locus_ids: [25, 26],
Query1.microorganism_ids: [12]
```

I also would like any suggestions on how to write more readable code

Comment: can you give example input and output?

Comment: Please provide example input and example output. It looks like it's just a function, so you can even create a code snippet (or any other sandbox example).

Comment: I've added input and output to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider using `reduce`?

```
export default (data) => Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, keyWithDot) => (
  Object.keys(data[keyWithDot]).forEach((key) => {
    acc[`${keyWithDot}.${key}`] = data[keyWithDot][key];
  }), 
  acc
), {});
```

You can also use `Object.fromEntries`, `map` and `flatMap` should do the job:

```
export default (data) => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(data).flatMap((keyWithDot) => 
      Object.keys(data[keyWithDot]).map((key) => [`${keyWithDot}.${key}`, data[keyWithDot][key]])
    )
  );
```

First, you build an array for each subentry, for each subentry, you flatten the array you got into an array of key/value, then with `Object.fromEntries`, you make a new object!

Comment: No, I didn't. I've never used the reduce method before. 
I like your solution, but can it also be done by map()?

Comment: I'll try a `map` version :)

Comment: Yes, please :) 
I just want to understand why my code didn't work

Comment: Thank you for the solution with the reduce method, though :)

Comment: Here it is :) I hope this is clear and that it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

What if the backend decides to add one more nesting? I would choose to go with a recursive function that accounts for that:

```js
function flattenObject(data) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value) || typeof value !== 'object') {
        // The condition might need to be changed depending on the expected data types
        return [[key, value]];
      }
      return Object.entries(flattenObject(value))
        .map(([suffix, nestedValue]) => [`${key}.${suffix}`, nestedValue]);
    })
  )
}
```

This works even for inputs such as:

```json
{
  query1: {
    nested: {
      test: true
    }
  },
  query2: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

The above example results in:

```json
{
  "query1.nested.test": true,
  "query2": [1,2,3]
}
```